# Regular expression for upper case letter only in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I validate a field only with upper case letters which are alphabetic. So, I want to match any word made of A-Z characters only.

Comment: Don't forget to accept one of the answers (see [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try something like this for the javascript validation:

```
if (value.match(/^[A-Z]*$/)) {
    // matches
} else {
    // doesn't match
}
```

And for validation on the server side in php:

```
if (preg_match("/^[A-Z]*$/", $value)) {
    // matches
} else {
    // doesn't match
}
```

It's always a good idea to do an additional server side check, since javascript checks can be easily bypassed.

Comment: @RohanKumar: That would be the same as `[A-Z]+`. Wasn't sure if you wanted zero or more (`*`) or one or more (`+`).

Comment: Sadly, this may ignore language specific diacritic characters. An `[:upper:]` character class equivalent would come in handy.

Comment: To support diacritics use unicode properties: `/^\p{Lu}+$/u.test(value)`

Answer (score 4):

```
var str = 'ALPHA';
if(/^[A-Z]*$/.test(str))
    alert('Passed');
else
    alert('Failed');
```

Comment: I think this will match "Aplha" as well.Just tried it here
http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html

Comment: @Rohan, Sorry I had an error for a second there. See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/YuYsk/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (<value>.match(/^[A-Z]*$/)) {
    // action if is all uppercase (no lower case and number)
} else {
    // else
}
```

here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WWhLD/